# How to draw out troops when clan castle is in middle of base

Tags: clash-of-clans

I just got 0 stars in a clan war attack because the clan castle was too deep inside the enemy base. I tried sending a giant to lure them out but it got stuck at the wall. I deployed a bunch more giants and they broke through the wall and the cc troops came and I tried to drop a lightening spell on them but they moved too fast.

How do you destroy the cc troops if the cc radius is still within the boundary of the buildings? If you drop 3 lightening spells on the castle while the troops are still inside would it destroy them?

Comment: If you have hogs, use one or two well placed hogs to get them out of the cc, then archers or barbs to draw them to the outside

Comment: Sounds like you're attacking something in the TH 7 or 8 range. Bases lower than that are too small to prevent you from luring out the CC troops (and even TH7 bases would need to be really spread out to do so). If that's the case, then why are you attacking with any ground troops at all? Using 3 lightning + 11 dragons will almost assuredly 3 star a TH7 base, and depending on the level of your dragons and the target's defenses, 2 or 3 star a TH8 base as well.

Comment: I assume you are a th8 since th7 below bases are too small to be unlurable. Try bringing a KillSquad, which consists of golems, wizards, and BK. Google kill squad and find out more.

Answer (score 2):

Analyse the base first:

1. Locate the defences on the perimeter that are within the clan castle radius. The perfect one would be the one that is located on the side from which you wish to attack.
2. After having chosen a defence to use to lure the cc, check if there is a wall hindering you from getting to the defence.
3. If there is a wall you will need hogs. If there is no wall you will need at least two giants. Two giants because there maybe a spring trap waiting for the first giant, so send them with maybe a one second difference between dropping them.
4. If there is a wall and a lot of defences around your chosen defence, you will need 2 or 3 hogs. This is because one hogs may get wiped out before it even reaches the intended target. The hogs may seat just outside of the clan castle radius when they reach the target so having three will make sure they plough it down quick and move deeper and therefore awakening the castle troops.
5. If there is no wall do not send your lure giants at once, send one first, if it gets flung out by a spring trap you still have a second one. Same applies for hogs, do not drop the lure hogs at once, if there is a trap they all get flung out (likely).

Special conditions:

1. If there is a wall and the clan castle is too deep, you will need a giant to distract the selected defence, and at least 3 or 4 hogs to wipe out the outer defences and then move in to a deeper defence to lure out the CC troops. Youtube search "giant hog lure" and you will definitely find this strategy.
2. If you absolutely want to use lightning to kill the cc, don't kill them while they are still moving. wait for them to stop moving/to settle in a cluster then drop that lightning.
3. If using dragons at TH7 or 8, destroying an air defence using three lightings works well. Your dragons will kill the cc themselves.
4. If you follow point 3 above. Do not drop your dragons on spot, if there are wizards in the clan castle they can wipe them out quickly or at least bring all their health down in that one spot. I have seen this happening a number of time with newbies.
5. If using dragons to try to get to a entered down hall, do not drop all of them in one spot, they will all go to the sides following the buildings on the perimeter. Instead, drop one on the left and one on the right with a space difference of 3 buildings, drop one in the middle. They will move on the perimeter, and leave an open space where they have cleaned up, this is where you drop your other dragons, they will definitely move towards the centre.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the castle was "too deep"? Best way to know is to view the base and click on the enemy castle. The circle drawn on the map shows you where a troop **must reach** to draw the CC troops.  By reach, I mean must occupy. An archer outside the castle radius attacking a building inside the castle radius doesn't count.

[@pnizzle's advice](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224670/how-to-draw-out-troops-when-clan-castle-is-in-middle-of-base/225056#225056) is spot on.

Sometimes the only troop you need is a barbarian, goblin or even a wall breaker.  Giant is recommended because it usually lives long enough to lure everything in the castle out, and is a ground troop. *Anything* in a clan castle will attack a ground unit, but if the CC contains e.g. balloons, a minion crossing into the castle radius will NOT draw out the CC contents. Only troops that are able to attack air troops respond to an air troop.

[image: Radius of a Castle. Troops must cross inside the white circle to draw out the Clan Castle Troops]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be at least TH7 or this shouldn't be a problem for you.

Attack the side the clan castle is closest too. If the person is farming, surround the entire base with your troops. To get at least one star, snipe the town hall if possible. If possible, reserve some troops and clan castle troops to deal with the enemy troops. Rage spells should be kept until the troops are drawn out, and when your own troops realize there are enemy troops, use a rage spell to help your troops finish them off easily. Be wary of powerful troops like balloons and dragons though.

Hogs might be good, they do cost some dark elixir though. Hogs can jump over walls and reach where the other troops cannot. Really, the best way is to charge in with most of your troops and rage them up while fighting enemy troops. Most people in Legend or Champion leagues do this method. Otherwise, place one troop and draw them out then massacre them with poison spells and your other troops.

Answer (score 0):

Use 1 Hog rider(send him close to cc as possible) to lure CC it works great! and u can use balloon if u don't have Hog Rider unlocked.